# How I calculate the SUM of left joined table in PHP grouped by transaction column

Tags: mysql, join, sum, left-join, union

I have read all the threads related to this same but it all was not helpful for me. since that I have made a sample design which helps I can easily learn.
I am trying to make SQL in PHP where it will fetch and give the expected result. When I doing left Join it is multiplying the joint row.
I have the same product SKU in the table multiple times but I wish it will give output each transaction wish so that help I can validate which transaction production have pending yet from the total request.

Please help me, tomorrow is my project submission date and due to this trouble, I haven't done breakfast and meal.

Please help me to fetch the expected output.

table: product_name

```
ID  |  p_sku  |  p_name
------------------------
1   |  123    | XYZ   
------------------------
2   |  456    | UVW
------------------------
3   | 789     | RST
```

table: material_req

```
ID | prod_sku  |  req_qty  | transaction_id
----------------------------------------------
1  | 123       |  150      |  123456  <--
                                         | //Same Transaction Id
2  | 456       |  150      |  123456  <--
3  | 123       |  100      |  785695
```

table: table_approve

```
ID  |  req_p_sku  |  apr_qty  |  apr_tran  | req_trans
-------------------------------------------------------
1   |  123        |  50       | 256314     |  123456
2   |  123        |  50       | 256315     |  123456
3   |  456        |  150      | 256316     |  123456
4   |  123        |  16       | 256317     |  785695
```

expected output -

```
sku   | name   |  qty_in  |  qty_reqt  | ref_id_1 | ref_id_2 
------------------------------------------------------------
123   | XYZ    |  100     | 150        | 123456   | 256314
456   | UVW    |  150     | 150        | 123456   | 256315
123   | XYZ    |  16      | 100        | 785695   | 256317
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? pls show us your query and what is wrong with it?

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ Please help me how I make the SQL which give result the same

Comment: The expected output does not make any sense? 256315 in table_approve is for sku 123, but in your expected result that value is in ref_id_2 for sku 456? It is hard to know that the table contains and how they are connected. And where does 100(qty_in) in expected result come from? Is it 50+50 from table_approve, if so how do we know that these should be summarized?

Comment: ok, ignore `ref_id_2 ` column how I fetch further

Comment: This website is a venue for asking questions and the community giving answers. You have to try to solve your query then if get an error or got stuck, then the community will help you. Try it first! it is more fun!